# Importing oracle to hadoop

Tags: sql, hadoop, sqoop

I have one oracle table which takes 3 hours to respond to a select query. I was thinking about importing it into hadoop for processing.

Would it be a good idea ? If I will use hive to perform the same query, would there be any performance gain ?

If yes, then how should I import my table into hadoop? Since table has composite primary key, sqoop is not an option. One more thing, Should I use HBase? Which approach will be better?

Comment: I think a better approach would be to improve your query so that it runs faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance in hadoop depends on the Size of the data. If the data is really huge you can see performance improvement. If the data is small , its better to tweak your query.